# compiling R 3.3.1

Tags: r, linux, rhel6

I am trying to install `R-3.3.1` on a RHEL6 box on which I do not have `su` permissions.  Unfortunately the machine has older versions of `zlib`, `bzip2`, readline, `xz`, `pcre`, `curl`.  I do not have access to `yum repo` nor will the admins help with this.  So, I am have compiled those libraries as well and installed them in

```
<my home dir>/libs
    bzip2-1.0.6
    curl-7.48.0
    pcre-8.38
    readline-6.3
    xz-5.2.2
    zlib-1.2.8
```

When I run `ldd` on the .so files, I do NOT get any missing libraries.  The only minor issue is

```
lib> ldd libcurl.so.4.4.0
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffec49ff000)
        libidn.so.11 => /lib64/libidn.so.11 (0x00007f2371b4b000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f2371934000)  <== this does not point to the version I have compiled
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f237172c000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2371398000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f237117a000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003e79000000)
```

Although I have set the `CPPFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS` and `LIBS`, and compiling with `--with-zlib=<zlib dir>`.

Now when I run `./configure --without-x` after setting `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` so that the above versions of the libraries are used, I get the following error.

```
checking libcurl version ... 7.19.7
checking curl/curl.h usability... yes
checking curl/curl.h presence... yes
checking for curl/curl.h... yes
checking if libcurl is version 7 and >= 7.28.0... yes
checking if libcurl supports https... no
configure: error: libcurl >= 7.28.0 library and headers are required with support for https
```

Is there any way of getting `R` to compile without support for `https`?

Answer (score 2):

There is a disconnect between you saying you have

> curl-7.48.0

and the configure output

> checking libcurl version ... 7.19.7

You may need to try to override the auto-detection used by `configure` to have it find your version of curl.  There are switches, it also listens to environment variables, you could possibly create a local `~/lib/` and have `ld.conf` be aware of it.  But this is now a `configure` / `autoconf` question and less of an R issue.

Comment: Where do I post if it is a `configure` issue?  I thought I cannot change ld.conf if I do not have `su` rights.  I did set `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$SHARE/libs/zlib-1.2.8:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: I work on machines where I don't have this issue so no tip from the top of my head but as I said -- I'd research under `autoconf` / `configure` and less so under R.  Maybe start with something like `[configure] local library` in the search box above?

Comment: You could also try the r-sig-fedora list for RH/FC/CentOS related issues.